# How to reduce DTU Usage by my stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a system built in .net with an Azure SQL Database. I have a task scheduler table, so in certain situations when something happens in the system it ads a row to this table. Then i have a web job in .net, that checks this table every couple of seconds, and if there is a row there with a status "Pending" it updates this row to "in progress", and then my web job, does the necessary task, and finally it updates the row to "Complete". This all works fine, but the query to check the table is using 100% DTU. The databsae is on SQL Azure S2. There are normally around 500 rows in the table. It sometimes can grow to hundreds of thousands, but they get cleaned out every few weeks.

Can someone help me understand why this is using 100% of the DTU. I know it is run very frequently, but i feel it should not use 100% DTU.

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [tb].[TaskSchedulerItem_Select_NextToProcess]
(
@TaskSchedulerId int,
@DateLastUpdated datetime,
@CurrentDateTime datetime
)

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


Declare @TaskSchedulerItemId int

Select top 1 @TaskSchedulerItemId = TaskSchedulerItemId 
From TaskSchedulerItem 
Where 
(
ItemStatus in ('PENDING','FAILED')
or
(ItemStatus = 'IN PROGRESS' AND DateLastUpdated<DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,@CurrentDateTime))
)
and TaskSchedulerId=@TaskSchedulerId
ORDER BY DateLastUpdated asc


UPDATE [TaskSchedulerItem]
   SET 
      ItemStatus = 'IN PROGRESS',
      ItemStatusDescription = 'IN PROGRESS',
      DateLastUpdated = @CurrentDateTime
      output inserted.T`enter code here`askSchedulerId,inserted.TaskSchedulerItemId, inserted.ItemReferenceId,inserted.ItemStatus,inserted.ItemStatusDescription, inserted.DateCreated, inserted.DateLastUpdated, inserted.FailureCount
Where TaskSchedulerItemId = @TaskSchedulerItemId
and ItemStatus in ('PENDING','FAILED', 'IN PROGRESS')
```

Comment: Do you have an index on TaskSchedulerItemId? How many different TaskSchedulerId do you have?

Comment: Please post query plans. If possible post stats profile output.  Getting the right index is what you need to get this to run fast most likely

Comment: Please post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`, `CREATE INDEX...` etc) statements for your table.

Comment: Hi David Brosnan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to check the Query performance in Azure SQL database on Portal.

For exmple:
[image]

Click in the selected query which used max usage of CPU to get more details. It will show you the query statements and give us the **Performance recommendations**:
[image]

Hope this helps.